# UnRar Library For iPhone-Password Protected Rar Files

Tags: iphone, ios, rar, unrar

Do anyone knows how to extract password protected files using unRar4ios library?
I do my best to figure out the same. But failed. In the cpp wrapper class of unRar4ios the author didn't implemented the function for extracting rar files that are password protected. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the author of the [Unrar4iOS library](https://github.com/ararog/Unrar4iOS) updated his source to actually do [password-protected file extraction on October 7th](https://github.com/ararog/Unrar4iOS/commit/839360ec391587d29c49e0848a25974b550c5ed4).

Your hard work and [persistence](https://github.com/ararog/Unrar4iOS/issues/7) paid off!